# What's the difference between weak linkage vs using a COMDAT section?

Tags: c++, elf, linkage

Suppose I have multiple definitions of an object that are defined across different object files and I want to link them together. It seems  there are 2 ways of selecting which definition to use when linking these object files together: marking the symbol as weak, or putting it in it's own COMDAT section (in each of the object files).

The way I understand it (which could be wrong), weak linkage allows this by one definition of a symbol overriding the definition of another depending on link order. And COMDAT allows multiple definitions by placing the symbol in the unique COMDAT section, and choosing which section to use when linking.

I was told that these are orthogonal concepts to each other, but wasn't sure why one would use both instead of just one of them. For a more concrete example, I believe virtual tables in c++ that have no key function are defined in all modules they are used, and these modules can be linked together because the vtable itself is declared as both weak and in it's own COMDAT.

Answer (score 1):

> but wasn't sure why one would use both instead of just one of them.

Weak linkage is most often used when there are *different* (i.e. not equivalent) possible implementations of a function.

For example, `libc.a` can provide a *weak* definition of `pthread_mutex_lock` which does nothing, while `libpthread.a` will provide a *strong* definition of the same function which actually does lock the mutex.

The user code (`main.o`) can call `pthread_mutex_lock` blindly, and the correct thing will happen depending on whether `libpthread.a` is linked in or not.

This obviously wouldn't work if the linker was free to chose either `pthread_mutex_lock` (as would happen if they were both COMDAT symbols).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between comdat and weak symbols, from the [GCC Vague Linkage](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vague-Linkage.html#Vague-Linkage) documentation:

> Duplicate copies of these constructs will be discarded at link time. This is known as COMDAT support.
>
> On targets that don't support COMDAT, but do support weak symbols, GCC
> uses them. This way one copy overrides all the others, but the unused
> copies still take up space in the executable.

So they behave the same, but comdat approach doesn't use unnecessary space. The above document also describes when will the compiler emit these (for inline functions, VTables, template instantiations etc.).

The compiler (g++ and clang) will emit both a comdat section and a weak symbol (comdat section would be enough but I guess it emits both just in case the linker doesn't support comdat sections):

```
$ cat tt1.cpp 
struct s1 {
   virtual void f1() {}
};    
s1 s1;

$ g++ -S tt1.cpp
$ cat tt1.s | c++filt 
.section .text. ... ,s1::f1(),comdat
.weak s1::f1()
...
.section .data. ... ,vtable for s1,comdat
.weak vtable for s1
...
```

Note that in the generated assembly, comdat gets defined as `.section ... comdat` instead of `.comdat`. That apparently causes `objdump` and `readelf` not to recognize it as such, they only show them as weak symbols:

```
$ g++ -c tt1.cpp && readelf -s tt1.o | c++filt 
...
    17: 0000000000000000    11 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT    8 s1::f1()
    19: 0000000000000000    24 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT   11 vtable for s1
...
```

We can verify the behaivor of weak symbols and comdat sections with this example:

```
$ cat aa.s
    .data
    .globl  var1
    .type   var1, @object
var1:
    .byte   0xb

$ cat aa2.s
    .data
    .globl  var1
    .type   var1, @object
var1:
    .byte   0xc

$ cat aa3.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern char var1;

int main() {
    printf("var1 = %0x%x\n", var1);
}

$ as aa.s -o aa.o && as aa2.s -o aa2.o && gcc aa3.c aa2.o aa.o
    aa.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `var1'
    aa2.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here

# symbols are neither weak nor in comdat,
# as expected we got multiple definition error

$ cat aa.s
    .data
    .globl  var1
    .weak   var1
    .type   var1, @object
var1:
    .byte   0xb

$ cat aa2.s
    .data
    .globl  var1
    .weak   var1
    .type   var1, @object
var1:
    .byte   0xc

$ as aa.s -o aa.o && as aa2.s -o aa2.o && gcc aa3.c aa2.o aa.o && ./a.out
var1 = 0xc
# change order of aa.o and aa2.o
$ gcc aa3.c aa.o aa2.o && ./a.out
var1 = 0xb
# only weak symbols, it worked

$ objdump -D ./a.out
...
0000000000201010 <var1>:
  201010:   0b                      .byte 0xb
  201011:   0c                      .byte 0xc
# both values are emitted, only the fist is used

$ cat aa.s
    .data
    .section    .data.var1,"aG",@progbits,var1,comdat
    .globl  var1
    .type   var1, @object
var1:
    .byte   0xb

$ cat aa2.s
    .data
    .section    .data.var1,"aG",@progbits,var1,comdat
    .globl  var1
    .type   var1, @object
var1:
    .byte   0xc

$ as aa.s -o aa.o && as aa2.s -o aa2.o && gcc aa3.c aa2.o aa.o && ./a.out
var1 = 0xc
# change order
$ as aa.s -o aa.o && as aa2.s -o aa2.o && gcc aa3.c aa.o aa2.o && ./a.out
var1 = 0xb
# only comdat, it worked

$ objdump -D ./a.out
0000000000201010 <var1>:
  201010:   0b                      .byte 0xb

# only a single value is emitted
```